# Create dynamically methods

Tags: php, oop

I have a config.php with a structure similar to this

```
$config = array(
'database' => array(
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => '',
    'database' => ''
),
'smtp' => array(
    'host' => '',
    'protocol' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => ''
)
);
```

How can dynamically create methods inside a class to get values? Something with this structure:

```
class Config{
    public function getDatabaseUsername(){}
    public function getDatabasePassword(){}
    .......
}
```

Comment: Dynamically during runtime or in the IDE? If the second, use an IDE which has a code generation support.

Answer (score 0):

In java, IDEs are smart enough to generate getter and setters for class attributes. I assume there must be the same feature in some IDE for php too.

May be you can write a generic function to do so like this one:

```
function getSystemconfig($innerArray,$key){
   if(key_exists($innerArray,$config) && key_exists($key,$config[$innerArray])
     return $config[$innerArray][$key];
}
```

You may call it like

```
 getSystemconfig("database","username");
```

Basically checking it the keys are valid and they exist in the array and then returning the value against that key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic methods [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) or [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)

### __call

Magic methods are predefined functions that allow you to catch access to the object that isn't there, for example:

```
class Magic
{

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {

        if ($name === "hello") {
            echo "Hello " . $arguments[0];
        }
    }

}
```

Note that "hello" is not a defined function, but it can now be called by the $magic object.

```
$magic = new Magic();
$magic->hello("World");
```

results in

> Hello World

So, in your example, you could write

```
class Config{
        public function __call($name, $arguments) {

            if ($name === "getDatabaseUsername") {
                return $this->config["database"]["username"];
            }
        }
}
```

### __get

You could also use the `__get` magic method, which allows you to get inaccessible properties.  So you could write:

```
class Config{
        public function __get($name) {

            if ($name === "username") {
                return $this->config["database"]["username"];
            }
        }
}
```

and then username could be accessed as if it was a property:

```
$config = new Config();
echo $config->username;
```